# Electricity: Ohm law vs Power in the Water analogy

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, flow, power

I'm trying to understand electricity principles with the water analogy. I know this analogy is not perfect, but so far it has helped me the most.

To recap:

- voltage (volt) is like water pressure
- current (ampere) is like flow rate
- resistance (ohm) is like the diameter of the pipe

So this explain nicely Ohm's law ($I=V/R$). Indeed, increasing pressure (i.e. increasing voltage) with constant pipe diameter would result in flow rate (current) increase. So far so good.

But then comes power: $P=VI$. Intuitively, it makes sense: the power should be proportional to the flow rate (current) and the pressure (voltage).

However if you really think about it, the current $I$ is already taking into account the voltage ($I=V/R$). Then how does it make sense to multiply the current (which already takes into account voltage) by the voltage again?

Comment: _"how does it make sense to multiply the current [...] by the voltage again?"_ Because it works. _"current I is already taking into account the voltage."_ Sure, which means we can write power $P=\frac{V^2}{R}$

Comment: [Why is Power = Voltage $\times$ Current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/705310/why-is-power-voltage-times-current)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to consider the sense. This is trivial if you consider the definitions.
$$\text{Power}=\frac{\text{Energy}}{\text{time}}=\frac Et$$
$$\text{Voltage}=\frac{\text{Energy}}{\text{Charge}}=\frac EQ$$
$$\text{Current}=\frac{\text{Charge}}{\text{time}}=\frac Qt$$
It should be then obvious that
$$P=\frac Et=\frac EQ\cdot\frac Qt=VI$$
There is no need for force your understanding of this to corroborate with the water flow analogy.